Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nextSibling') on Vue using vueform
Sometimes when I am browsing, and I do actions such as going back or to a window after having reloaded, I get this error and a blank screen is shown, and those screens have vueform components, I don't know if it is a vue or vueform bug .
I would like you to tell me if it is a vueform error or what it is, and if anyone knows how to solve it. I'm using "nuxt": "3.0.0" and "@vueform/nuxt": "^1.4.0".
this is the complete error shown in console:
chunk-CWWVL7AG.js?v=e3cfca20:8450 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nextSibling')
    at nextSibling (chunk-CWWVL7AG.js?v=e3cfca20:8450:35)
    at removeFragment (chunk-CWWVL7AG.js?v=e3cfca20:5550:14)
    at remove2 (chunk-CWWVL7AG.js?v=e3cfca20:5521:9)
    at unmount (chunk-CWWVL7AG.js?v=e3cfca20:5499:9)
    at unmountComponent (chunk-CWWVL7AG.js?v=e3cfca20:5567:7)
    at unmount (chunk-CWWVL7AG.js?v=e3cfca20:5482:7)
    at unmountComponent (chunk-CWWVL7AG.js?v=e3cfca20:5567:7)
    at unmount (chunk-CWWVL7AG.js?v=e3cfca20:5482:7)
    at Object.resolve (chunk-CWWVL7AG.js?v=e3cfca20:2402:11)
    at chunk-CWWVL7AG.js?v=e3cfca20:2512:20


Do you have nextSibling somewhere in your code?

No, I think it happens when I reload in a tab that has vueform elements and I redirect to another tab, in that other tab I get the error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nextSibling')
